# How do I pipe stdout of continuously running node scripts into a ruby script

Tags: ruby, pipe, stdout

I have `numbers.rb`

```
loop do
  puts rand(10)
  sleep(1)
end
```

I have `pipe.rb`

```
ARGF.each_line do |line|
  puts "received #{line}"
end
```

I'm trying to pipe output of number.rb to pipe.rb. Like this –

```
ruby lib/numbers.rb | ruby pipe.rb
```

However, this doesn't do what I want it to do. Basically, the piped input doesn't seem to be recieved until the process number.rb stops executing. But numbers.rb isn't supposed to end. How do I pipe the stdout of numbers.rb continuously, as it happens, to pipe.rb?

Answer (score 1):

10 seconds after having posted this question, figured the answer out. Have to put `$stdout.sync = true` at the top of `numbers.rb`

Comment: Instead of writing what is basically a comment in an answer, improve this by showing a complete working example, then when Stack Overflow lets you you can select it as the answer.